# CSS - text overflow: display 2 lines of text only

Tags: css

Given a long string of content, I want to display just the first 2 lines of text. The container of this content is fluid and will resize to the browser's width. Regardless of the container's width, I want the text to always only show 2 lines. Is there a way to do this?

If there is no way to do the above, is there a way to restrict based on number of characters?

Answer (score 10):

This snippet will help you.

Just Adjust **Max-Height** and **Line-height** for the change in font size.

```
 .limit-2 {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: -webkit-box;
    line-height: 21px;
    max-height: 48px;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
 }
```

Comment: I think you meant `max-height: 44px` (2 x 21)

Comment: @Utkanos yes. but it does depend on the font-size too.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the height of the div and make `overflow` as `hidden`

```
    div{
    height:auto;
    max-height:40px;
    overflow:hidden; 
    background:red
}
```

**[DEMO UPDATED](http://jsfiddle.net/fpvYB/5/)**

**OR**

Use simple `Jquery` method

```
$('p').condense({ellipsis:'&hellip;', condensedLength: 55});
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/HAtgn/163/)**

Comment: In your demo, I would just get rid of the `width` attribute so it'll just adjust to the width of the container, right? The problem is that there is a possibility that there will only be one line. By defining the height, that means the space used will always be the same regardless of content?

Comment: In that case you can mention max-height:40px and height:auto. Check the updated DEMo

Comment: A note for Googlers, `condense` isn't a built-in jQuery function, and requires [a plugin](https://github.com/jsillitoe/jquery-condense-plugin) to use.

Answer (score 1):

A pure CSS solution would imply the use of a stated height for the text block and the ´text-overflow`property. This is rather difficult to achieve because CSS has no notion of lines. A JavaScript solution, instead, would imply a regular expression matching for the newline character.

Answer (score 1):

I have idea of some workaround to solve your problem (couse I think this is not possible by css).

So, my solution works as follow:

```
var height = parseInt($("#foo").css("line-height"));
var lineCount = 2;
height *= lineCount;

$("#foo").css("height", height + "px");
```

You take `line-height` of your container and set `height` of container to `line-height * lineCount`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k4Srg/)